# How to replace some characters with "x" with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm working on a Magento project and, in the customer dashboard, there is a field that here in Brazil it's our federal ID called "CPF" (originally from Magento, it's called VAT) and I inserted an IF to check if customer is on its account page and add a "disabled" attribute. Just to make more professional, instead of displaying all number, I would like to replace some digits by "x". The CPF format is like below (that is a fake number, just to illustrate):

**168.828.835-05**

I would like to display only first three digits and last 2 digits, by replacing digits in the middle with "x", so:

**168.xxx.xxx-05**

I created a function to get the length of my input value and applying a different replace for each one, but it's not working. Check it out:

```
function mask_vat(inputID) {
    var mystr = document.getElementById(inputID).value;
    var str_length = mystr.length;
    var pattern, replacement;
        switch(str_length) {
            case 14:
                pattern = '/^(\d{3}).\d{3}.\d{3}-(\d{2})$/';
                replacement = '$1.XXX.XXX-$2';
                break;
            case 18:
                pattern = '/.\d{3}.\d{3}\//';
                replacement = '.xxx.xxx/';
                break;
        }
    mystr.replace(pattern, replacement);
}
```

what's wrong in the function??

Comment: Is number length is fixed for all case.?

Comment: Actually not. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following RegEx replacers:

```
// Replace '168.828.835-05' with CPF value
'168.828.835-05'.replace(/^(\d{3}).\d{3}.\d{3}-(\d{2})$/,'$1.XXX.XXX-$2')
```

or (if segments have variable length)

```
// Replace '168.828.835-05' with CPF value
'168.828.835-05'.replace(/.\d+.\d+-/,'.XXX.XXX-')
```

For example:

```
function maskCPF(cpf) {
    return cpf.replace(/^(\d{3}).\d{3}.\d{3}-(\d{2})$/,'$1.XXX.XXX-$2');
}

maskCPF('168.828.835-05');
```

If you were to do it server side in PHP:

```
<?php
    $cpf = '168.828.835-05';
    $pattern = '/^(\d{3}).\d{3}.\d{3}-(\d{2})$/';
    $replacement = '$1.XXX.XXX-$2';
    $masked_cpf = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $cpf);
?>
```

Comment: Great, I will try that. Just a question: Is it safe doing that on client side? Would it better using that mask on server side, using PHP for example?

Comment: @joaogdesigner: Server side would be definitely better.

Comment: That's what I thought. Even this question is tagged with jquery, do you know how to do it in PHP?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Maybe I will have to accept for that field another number format, which is for companies ID, because "CPF" is for individuals. The company ID (called here "CNPJ") has this format: 00.000.000/0001-00. It would be possible using a different pattern for that, I mean, 00.xxx.xxx/xxxx-00? I would count the characters from db to identify if it's CPF or CNPJ, and then, applying the pattern.

Comment: Sure. You can experiment with different patterns for different formats.

Comment: What would be the pattern to get 51.xxx.xxx/0001-48?

Comment: You can use `/.\d{3}.\d{3}\//` pattern with `.xxx.xxx/` as a replacer

Comment: I forgot an important factor: after masking the number, it isn't passing through validation. Is there a way to "bypass" that specific input when saving customer info on that page?

Comment: You can update your validation logic to handle such case. But there is more than one way to achieve this. And as an app owner, only you might be able to figure out what's the most optimal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need jQuery to manipulate a string, you can try this function:

```
function maskWithX (str) {
    return str.replace(/\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-/, ".xxx.xxx-");
}
```

Comment: Nothing in particular, I'm just used to work with jQuery, so I don't know the pure js...

Comment: @joaogdesigner jQuery don't really have string manipulation functions, so you would need to use built-in functions of "native" JS.

Answer (score 1):

[Assuming that the input numbers are of fixed length]

You can use this function below to accomplish what you want.

```
   function changetToX(input) {
     return input.substring(0, 3) + 'xxx.xxx-' + input.substring(input.length - 2);
    }
```

Comment: Is the function's parameter the ID or the name of my input?

Comment: You will use this function as `changeToX('168.828.835-05')`;

Answer (score 0):

Here the logic

```
var replaccelength= str.substring(4,str.length-3).length;
alert(str.substring(0, 4) + Array(replaccelength).join("x") + str.substring(str.length-3));
```